# Make WCF service hosted in IIS Express always running without request

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that hosted in IIS Express and it has a function that gets the frame from camera continuously. But that function only run when I request to get that frame, without any request, the frame is not got by service. So do we have any ways to make WCF service keep running without request?
Note: I'm using IIS Express not IIS.

Comment: I don't think so in iis you can do that, iis is a passive listener unlike self sevices.

Comment: Do we have any solution for this? I don't want to make a while(true) to the service to keep it alive. And how about change it hosted to console app

Comment: Instead of console, it would be better as Windows service entry.

Comment: Why don't you go with `Window service` or Desktop application?

Comment: I'm using WCF hosted in IIS Express. Does it easy to transfer it to Window Service or Desktop App? Because I have no time now

Comment: You can but it's generally not recommended.  I don't know about IIS Express but in IIS you set the AppPool to not expire/recycle.  That or you continually poll your IIS/Express app.  As others have said, look into Windows Services or a desktop app.  If you have setup your solution right its pretty easy